# Ruby version gemfile conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've seen a couple of questions about this but none that solve my issue

So i try to bundle instal and I get the following error:

```
bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0
```

But when I check my Ruby version...

```
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

also:

```
rvm rubies

ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ missing bin/ruby ]
=* ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.2.1 [ missing bin/ruby ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

recently I spend the same, to solve it by doing the following:

```
gem install bundler
```

remember that if you are using rvm run

```
rvm use ruby-2.2.0
```